# How to get only words from the string using python

Tags: string, python-2.7

I have a file which has special characters, so I used file operations to read.

```
f=open('st.txt','r')
string=f.read()
```

The sample string is

```
"Free Quote!\n          \n          Protecting your family is the best investment you\'ll eve=\nr \n"
```

now I want to remove all the special characters and get only the words from the string.
so that my string will be:

```
"Free Quote Protecting your family is the best investment you'll ever"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is a simple loop testing against `string.ascii_letters` plus a specific subset of extra characters (e.g., `'-`):

```
>>> import string
>>> text = "Free Quote!\n \n Protecting your family is the best investment you\'ll eve=\nr \n"
>>> ''.join([x for x in text if x in string.ascii_letters + '\'- '])
"Free Quote  Protecting your family is the best investment you'll ever "
```

As you edit longer and more complex texts, excluding specific punctuation marks becomes less sustainable, and you'd need to use more complex regex (for example, when is a `'` an apostrophe or a quote?), but for the scope of your problem above, this should suffice.

Comment: Glad to hear that.  If this answer worked for you, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) so that people know that the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I found 3 solutions but there all close but not exactly what you want.

```
import re
in_string = "Free Quote!\n \n Protecting your family is the best investment you\'ll eve=\nr \n"

#variant 1
#Free Quote Protecting your family is the best investment youll eve r 
out_string = ""
array = "Free Quote!\n \n Protecting your family is the best investment you\'ll eve=\nr \n".split( )
for word in array:
    out_string += re.sub(r'[\W]', '', word) + " "
print(out_string)

#variant 2
#Free Quote Protecting your family is the best investment you ll eve r
print(" ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", in_string)))

#variant 3
#FreeQuoteProtectingyourfamilyisthebestinvestmentyoullever
print(re.sub(r'[\W]', '', in_string))
```

Comment: If you see the output, the special characters like ! and = are not removed and \n which gave the next line.
I want the output to be as below
"Free Quote Protecting your family is the best investment youll ever"

Comment: I update the question but unfortunately the solutions are just close